# MySQL Insert specified value and found value into a table on a condition

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I found several similar questions, but none that got me past my roadblock. (This one is close [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340))

I need to read all the IDs except one from one table and then update another table with them. The destination table has 2 columns. One of those columns must be that foreign id. I want the other column to be a number I hard code into the query.

like this:

```
letter_id drop_letter_id
10        99
```

What happens in the application is that if someone subscribes to letter 10, then it unsubscribes them from letter 99. I want 99 to be exclusive to those that are not subscribed to anything else so I need to find all the letter ids that are not 99 and add them to this drop table as

```
letter_id drop_letter_id
x        99
y        99
```

where x and y are other letter id numbers.

sort of like

```
SELECT letter_id FROM letters WHERE letter_is<>99
```

and then

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO letter_drops (x,99)...
```

Comment: [Stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html)?

Comment: @CORRUPT, I've never used them and I am not certain my system is set up for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got correctly, it's:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO letter_drops SELECT letter_id, 99 FROM letters WHERE letter_id!=99
```

Comment: Thanks. I can usually read sql queries a lot better than I write them. That looks right. I'll try it. So, the `SELECT 99` just puts `99` where a value might otherwise be selected?

Comment: Quite so. You can use `SELECT` with any valid expression. Scalar value is, of cause, valid expression.

Comment: You query does what I asked. Now I'm going to complicate it a little. This DB is part of an application and I don't want to change the structure of the database if I can avoid it. I was working on a copy of the table in question and I ended up with duplicates, so apparently they did not design it to keep the rows unique. How would you suggest I prevent this script from making duplicate rows given this info?

Comment: Well - it is too different question, so I suggest to ask in another thread where you will be able to describe your problem full and clear